# Enable Trace/Debug logs for JMS client of Websphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

How do I enable Trace or DEBUG level logging in the JMS client of Websphere IBM MQ.

I have no control over server and it doesn't even run in our infrastructure.

Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: What version of the client?

Comment: Note there have been some recent changes that may not be reflected in the technote or knowledge center links that @a_cornish_pasty provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want instructions for tracing the MQ classes for JMS, try using your favourite search engine.  You'll probably come across this Technote:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21174924#Java

that has details for different product versions and environments.

Alternatively, why not look in thte "Toubleshooting and support" section of the production documentation in the IBM Knowledge Center:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q031860_.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the trace log easily using the command line argument below.

```
-Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=ON
```

Refer to the below link for more information on using this argument:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q131840_.htm#q131840_

For other options of enabling the trace:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q031860_.htm

Also, just bear in mind that the trace logs grow too large over time and affect performance. Try to use them in lower environments (not production) first and investigate your issues. You may also refer to the below link for more options on controlling the generated trace output.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27018159&aid=1